# I'm using FormsAuthentication, and am having trouble extending the expiry

Tags: c#, asp.net, formsauthentication

I'm building a web app (framework 4.6), and am using FormsAuthentication to manage the security.

Currently, it allows the user to log in/log out etc... and all is fine.
However, I want to periodically check the expiry of the Forms Authentication Ticket, and pop up a dialog box with a button that the user will press to extend the time.  So I basically have it working, except that when the ticket is renewed, the user is essentially kicked out, and I have no idea why.

Here's the logging in code:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket faTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.UserID, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes), persistLogin, "");
string cookiestr = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(faTicket);
HttpCookie ck = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookiestr);
if (persistLogin)
    ck.Expires = faTicket.Expiration;
ck.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(ck);
```

and here's the ticket renew code:

```
FormsIdentity identity = ((FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
string userID = identity.Name;
HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userID, true);
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    ticket.Version,
    userID,
    ticket.IssueDate, 
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes), 
    ticket.IsPersistent, 
    ticket.UserData, 
    ticket.CookiePath);

cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
if (ticket.IsPersistent)
    cookie.Expires = newTicket.Expiration;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Incidentally, the way I'm working on the time remaining is as follows (within a ashx handler file):

```
FormsIdentity identity = ((FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
DateTime expires = identity.Ticket.Expiration;

// offset the expiry time by a few seconds, because otherwise the FormsAuthentication will prevent this Handler from executing
expires = expires.AddSeconds(-5);

TimeSpan ts = expires - DateTime.Now;
double mins = ts.Minutes;
double secs = ts.Seconds;
string countdownText = mins.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + secs.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reissuing the ticket, it might make sense to set the issued date to the current date -->

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
    ticket.Version,
    userID,
    DateTime.Now,//ticket.IssueDate 
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes), 
    ticket.IsPersistent, 
    ticket.UserData, 
    ticket.CookiePath);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, but now i have a new problem with trying to extend (renew) an authentication ticket by 5 minutes, and the extra time I'm adding is not quite being stored on the ticket as current_time + 5 minutes.  Why would this be?

Comment: So in my Chrome console I'm outputting the actual expiration date as it should be, considering the current date stamp is 16/01/2016 12:54:01, the expiration date would be 16/01/2016 12:59:01)... but after setting this expiration date, and renewing the ticket, the date comes back as something like 16/01/2016 12:58:30.  I have no idea why it's almost a random 'approximation' of current_time + 5 minutes!?  What am I missing here?

Comment: My renew code:
`string userID = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
HttpCookie cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userID, true);
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);`

Comment: `DateTime NEWEXPIRY = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes);
FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version,userID,DateTime.Now,NEWEXPIRY,ticket.IsPersistent,ticket.UserData,ticket.CookiePath);
cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = newTicket.Expiration;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);`

Comment: Check the time on your server and make sure it is synced.